# Java 8 Optional: reference self in "orElse" function

Tags: java, java-8

Given this code:

```
class PositionValue {
    Object value;
    boolean deleted;
}

class Position {
    Optional<PositionValue> value = Optional.empty();
}

Position getPosition() {
    return positionRepository.findSomePosition();
}

Position findCorrectPosition() {
    Position position = getPosition();
    return position.value.map(this::finalizeOrNext).orElse(position);
}

Position finalizeOrNext(PositionValue positionValue) {
    if (positionValue.deleted) {
        return moveToNextPosition(positionValue);
    } else {
        return finalPosition(positionValue);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid explicitly declaring `position` variable in `findCorrectPosition`? In other words, I'd like `orElse` function to reference he result of `getPosition()` call.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do so. I think you've made the code as compact as it's going to get.

Comment: if you're positive about this feel free to post that as an actual answer

Comment: I think @Holger has answered the question correctly and more completely, so I'll let it be. However, I would say I prefer your current implementation to the one he suggested as a possible alternative. My feeling on this is that another layer of  indirection will only serve to muddy the waters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no “self” relationship in your code. The `Optional` contains a `PositionValue`, or well, doesn’t contain it, as `orElse` is only relevant if the `Optional` is empty.

The fact that there is a `Position` instance having a reference to that `Optional` is not establishing a special relationship; there might be plenty of other objects having a reference to that `Optional` too.

The only way to simplify the code is to create a support method at the place which knows the desired context, `Position`:

```
class Position {
    Optional<PositionValue> value = Optional.empty();
    public Position mapOrSelf(Function<? super PositionValue, ? extends Position> f) {
        return value.map(f).orElse(this);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
Position findCorrectPosition() {
    return getPosition().mapOrSelf(this::finalizeOrNext);
}
```

Comment: In general OPs design (having single `Optional` field inside another object) looks strange: why such double-boxing could be necessary? Nevertheless your solution looks the best under the assumption that such field is absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: right, having `Optional`s in field is an uncommon pattern. The good thing about the `mapOrSelf` method is that it would continue to work when retrofitting `Position` to not use `Optional`